# Open SSL Error in common lisp using the drakma library when accessing secure sites

Tags: http, https, common-lisp, drakma

I have the package drakma installed from quicklisp

Saying I am missing `Unable to load any of the alternatives: ("libcrypto.so.1.1" "libcrypto.so.1.0.0" "libcrypto.so") [Condition of type CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR]`

when trying to access non secure sites I am able to do so perfectly fine.
`(drakma:http-request "http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/")`

however, any other site that I try to access give the error of
`No OpenSSL version number could be determined, both SSLeay and OpenSSL_version_num failed.`

Example:
`(drakma:http-request "https://lisp.org")`

Why am I getting this error for secure sites exactly? and what can I do to mitigate this

Answer (score 2):

`Drakma` has [`cl+ssl`](https://cl-plus-ssl.common-lisp.dev/) as a dependency. *That* dependency is installed by Quicklisp, but `cl+ssl` itself has `libssl-dev` as a dependency. It turns out that `libcrypto.so` is a shared library that is distributed with `libssl-dev`.

`libssl-dev` is not a Common Lisp ASDF system, so you will have to install it yourself. The easiest way to do this would be to use a package manager, e.g., `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`.

Comment: yep that was the issue. I figured that out the hard way thanks !

Comment: @MichaelErbaturakis I suppose you can choose this answer as the solution? thanks.